# Add markup to form during validation

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I have a custom validator on a webform. When a person enters an address, I validate it. When the address is not right, I set an error in the validation function. This is all going well. But now I want to give the visitor suggestions when he enter a wrong address. This should be done by giving the suggestion in a markup underneath the address input.

I allready set up an empty markup field in the webform, now I just want to put information in it during validation. How is this possible. If you need any dpm or printout let me know please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In your validate you can set a variable in the `$form_state` that tells if the validation failed or not:

```
function webform_validate_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($mail_invalid) {
    $form_state['mail_invalid'] = TRUE;
  }
  else {
    $form_state['mail_invalid'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Then in your form, you can check for `empty($form_state['mail_invalid'])` and show the markup when the empty check returns false.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  ...
  if (!empty($form_state['mail_invalid']) {
    $form['markup'] = ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I alter the form then ? hook_form_alter is called BEFORE validation handler, and if I change any varible in $form in the validation hook, nothing happens.

Comment: @Nealv You didn't read my answer properly, I have updated my answer to clearly show what I'm talking about. You need to check `$form_state` like I explained.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the "validation" hook is called AFTER the form alter. so when the form_alter is executed, $form_state['mail_invalid'] will be NULL, because you set it afterwards. right

Comment: @Nealv That is why you use the `empty()` to check it. First time around it won't exist so `!empty() == FALSE` in order words the markup isn't added to the form. If the validation fails, the form is rebuild, but this time `!empty() == TRUE` so the markup is shown. This is really quite simple.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but there is no first and second time. flow is like this: hook_form_alter -> hook_validate -> render. So after the validation I cant change anything in the form, and during neither because the form is not a reference but a copy. Is it possible to chat ?

Comment: could you help me out please, I am really stuck, for days :S

Comment: @googletorp can't we alter the form right from the validate function ? $form is passed by reference and I have done some minor changes in validate functions before (like makring fields readonly, etc) so I'm wondering if there is a specific reason why you don't alter the form in validate function.